# Seeking Equity Split Advice between four co-founders, two of them who have invested money and two who haven't

Tags: stocks, start-up, equity, corporation, partnership

Founder A,B,C,D are equally responsible for the execution and the idea. At the pre-development stage, Founder A invests $12,500 and Founder B invests $7,500, whereas Founder C and D aren't investing any funds. Moreover, Founder A and B are seeking to get their full amount of investment back once the company starts generating revenue. What should be a fair equity split?

Comment: Did they loan the company the money or use it to purchase stock?

Comment: Fair is whatever everyone agrees.

Comment: Founder A and B have essentially used the initial funding to purchase stock. However, part of the question is that if they get repaid once the company starts making profit, then should they really be holding on to that stock or should the stock go back to the company?